# What is an "island of richness"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I'm looking on how to incorporate silverlight in my existing application and I keep running into the latest buzz-phrase "island of richness".  What does it mean?

Thanks!

Comment: it's referenced here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2008/02/18/islands-of-richness-with-silverlight-on-an-asp-net-page.aspx

Comment: @Burt I believe that's the smell of Marketing...

Comment: Looks like ActiveX for 2011, Now With Extra Buzzwords.

Comment: @Bala: I did read that.  The article is a little old 2008 :(.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An [island of richness](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2008/02/18/islands-of-richness-with-silverlight-on-an-asp-net-page.aspx) is a (relatively) small area of rich, dynamic content (e.g. Silverlight, Flash, or heavy AJAX) on a page which is mostly regular HTML. It's as opposed to a page whose entire content is Silverlight-enabled.

So basically, it's when the page contains some Silverlight content, but that isn't the only content in the page.

Answer (score 3):

It simply means that rather than having an entire webpage/site as a Silverlight application, you have small Silverlight apps for specific usage.  Such as a media player, chat window, etc.

Comment: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2008/02/18/islands-of-richness-with-silverlight-on-an-asp-net-page.aspx for an example.

Comment: Multiple apps?   What do you mean?

Comment: @subt13 one application would be a media player, one application would be a chat window, one application would could be an interactive advertisement spinner.  They all would be on the webpage, but they are loaded independently and can function as such, but they could also pass information between each other for an enhanced experience.

Comment: Sorry to be picky, but are you talking about multiple silverlight projects, multiple xap files, multiple dlls, multiple xaml files?

Comment: @subt13 it would be multiple xaps embedded into an HTML page, similar to how you can have multiple swfs (Flash) embedded into an HTML page.

Comment: @Brain I started a new question about this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046217/whats-a-silverlight-plugin

Answer (score 1):

It means the content delivered by the Silverlight plugin is an island of rich user interface in a sea of less rich HTML.

If you take YouTube as an example (although it uses flash rather than silverlight) the video player is the "island of richness" in the rest of the page which is all HTML.

Comment: It hosts your silverlight content within the browser.

Answer (score 1):

It means that you're hosting a silverlight plugin within an aspx page (or html/whatever). The plugin being the island of richness.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server" style="height:100%">
        <h1>Sample Text </h1>
        <div>Other Non-Rich Content</div>
        <div id="silverlightControlHost">
            <!-- Begin Island of Richness -->
            <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
              <param name="source" value="../Common/silverlightbin/Granite.EHR.ImmunizationAdmin.xap"/>
              <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
              <param name="background" value="#D7D7D7" />
              <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50826.0" />
              <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
              <param name="initparams" value="control=Admin" />
              <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.50826.0" style="text-decoration:none">
                  <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
              </a>
            </object><iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe></div>
            <!-- END Island of Richness -->
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @subt13 - the plugin is the xap silverlight file. You include it in your page similarly to a flash plugin.

Comment: Could it also be a direct reference to the xaml file, or does it have to be a xap file?

Comment: I started another question on this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046217/whats-a-silverlight-plugin